# Compiling .py-file to .exe in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

I can't figure get py2exe working.

I wish to convert this test.py to test.exe:

test.py code:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently I used python 2.x approach. When I instead used the 3.3 command:

```
 py -3.3 -m py2exe.build_exe test.py
```

I got the new error:

```
 D:\program\python\lib\distutils\dist.py:257: UserWarning: Unknown     distribution o
 ption: 'console'
 warnings.warn(msg)
 invalid command name 'test.py'
```

Feels as if I am just running into walls constantly. Any insight on this new error?

**Old part of post:**

I have created a setup.py with the following code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['test.py'])
```

I installed py2exe (ver 0.9.2.2) with pip. When I move to the folder containing setup.py and test.py and run the command:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

I run into the error:

```
 D:\program\python\lib\distutils\dist.py:257: UserWarning: Unknown distribution o
 ption: 'console'
   warnings.warn(msg)
 usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
    or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
    or: setup.py --help-commands
    or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'py2exe'
```

Comment: That a Python 2 setup execution, use this instead: `py -3.4 -m py2exe.build_exe test.py`

Comment: Thanks Malik. I looked it up and you're correct; however, it still does not work. Any clue as to why not?

Answer (score 0):

The python documentation discourages the use of the `distutils` module.  Instead use `setuptools` as follows

```
from setuptools import setup
import py2exe

setup(scripts=['test.py'])
```

Under python 3 though, you can't use `py2exe` see the [FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html?#how-do-i-make-an-executable-from-a-python-script) for details.

Comment: Tried it, but it did not work. As far as I understand, this is simply an extension of the python2.x way to solve the problem? I am running python3.3.